# How to fire a shot nicely without any problems?

Tags: ios, swift, skspritenode

When a button is pressed, a shot node is fired from a character node's position and moves to x direction. If it is collided with a node, then both nodes disappear.

```
func attackButton() {

    _weapon.removeFromParent()

    _weapon.position = CGPointMake(character.position.x, charater.position.y)
    _weapon.startMoving()
    addChild(_weapon)
    character.throwWeapon()
}
```

When this function is triggered, normally it works without any problem. However, when I press `jumpButton`, which enables the character to jump to the Y direction, and 'attackButton', the character's coordinates are somehow affected. The character moves and sometimes rotates. From my code, I never wrote anything that causes it to move to different directions. This gets me annoying. I cannot come up with any solution to prevent that from occurring. Is there anyone who knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're providing less code than I'm able to work from so I'm going to say what I think that is happening:

The weapon is being spawned at the exact same position as the character but it's being moved out of it really quickly by the physics engine. This positional correction applies impulses to the character body, causing it to rotate.

You can solve this problem in two different ways:

- Spawn the weapon outside the character, or...
- Disable collisions between weapon and character.

Try changing your 5th line to something like this:

```
_weapon.position = CGPointMake(character.position.x + character.size.width / 2, charater.position.y)
```

Comment: This does not work.. Is it because I am using SKAction? Usually, is it a good practice to use SKAction to fire a shot, instead of writing a method in update method?

Comment: I don't think your problem relates to the usage of `SKAction`. Try to spawn the weapon elsewhere, not close to the character, to see if your problem gets solved.

Comment: And yes, I think using `SKAction` in that scenario sounds like a good practice. But I'm not sure tbh, because I'm not familiar with Swift.

Comment: Heeey! Seems like it is working very nice! Avoiding putting the shot node on the character was the solution. Big thanks! I am feeling so happy!!!

Comment: Ahh wait, I have one more question that would make this action nicer. If I press the button, a shot is born but double tap deletes the first tapped shot node. Once a shot node is produced, I want that to be on the screen as long as it is off the screen edge. Is there any way that can be written in the method above?

Comment: Mmm I don't know, as I said I'm not familiar with swift and its workflow. Maybe you should ask a new question. ;)

Comment: Okay, I will! Thanks for your answer :)